# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command Failed executing DbCommand (size=-1)

Tags: entity-framework, parameters, size, dbcommand

I don't know why parameter 8 has size of -1. In EntityFramework, this property has a maxlength of 75 and the column in the database is a nvarchar(75). It's the only parameter to have wrong size.

[2022-11-01 00:13:30.381 -04:00] [Error] [AC-PEL1:73] [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command] Failed executing DbCommand ("13"ms) [Parameters=["@p0='?' (Size = 10), @p1='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p2='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p3='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p4='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p5='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p6='?' (Size = 100), @p7='?' (DbType = Guid), **@p8='?' (Size = -1)**, @p9='?' (DbType = Int32), @p10='?' (Size = 100), @p11='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p12='?' (Size = 2000), @p13='?' (Size = 100), @p14='?' (Size = 2000), @p15='?' (Size = 2000), @p16='?' (Size = 2000)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"
`""SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT INTO [Pel].[DemandeInterventions] ([CodeIntervention], [DateCourriel], [DateDerniereModifExterne], [DateEffectuee], [DateIntervention], [DatePrevue], [Description], [EmailId], **[Etat]**, [IdDemande], [IntervenantExterne], [InterventionExterne], [MessageCourriel], [NomEmploye], [NoteClient], [NoteCourriel], [NoteInterne]) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16); SELECT [Id] FROM [Pel].[DemandeInterventions] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();"`

I want to insert data in my database and i want parameter 8 to be like all others parameters the mix size of the property (75) not -1